# Release a button after being tapped then dragged outside it's bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i'm working on app with sprite kit. In the app, there is an up, left, right buttons for the hero to navigate in the app. they all work good except for a bug that i just discovered which happens when i tap on one of the buttons and i drag outside the button, the hero doesn't stop moving. the buttons are base on the event UiControlEventTouchDown so that i have this continuous motion. is there any solution for this problem? i wanted to post the code but i don't think it will help because it's only the definition of the methods that get's called when the buttons are pressed. oh, i tried the touchesBegan: method in my scene but it can't track a drag on screen after a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

okay solved my problem. i implemented three target:actions first one when the button is tapped second when the user lift his finger after tapping directly and another one if the user tapped the button then dragged to outside and lifted up. here's the code.

```
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLeftPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLeftReleased) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLeftReleased) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```